# Word popularity leaderboard in SQL Server based message-board

Tags: sql-server, split, group-by, sum, alphanumeric

In a SQL server database, I have a table `Messages` with the following columns:

- Id `INT(1,1)`
- Detail `VARCHAR(5000)`
- DatetimeEntered `DATETIME`
- PersonEntered `VARCHAR(25)`

Messages are pretty basic, and only allow alphanumeric characters and a handful of special characters, which are as follows:

```
`¬!"£$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:'@#~\|,<.>/?
```

Ignoring the bulk of the special characters bar the apostrophe, what I need is a way to list each word along with how many times the word occurs in the Detail column, which I can then filter by `PersonEntered` and `DatetimeEntered`.

Example output:

```
Word    Frequency
-----------------
a       11280
the     10102
and      8845
when     2024
don't    2013
.
.
.
```

It doesn't need to be particularly clever. It is perfectly fine if `dont` and `don't` are treated as separate words.

I'm having trouble splitting out the words into a temporary table called `#Words`.

Once I have a temporary table, I would apply the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Word, 
    SUM(Word) AS WordCount 
FROM #Words 
GROUP BY Word 
ORDER BY SUM(Word) DESC
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would strip out almost all the special characters, and then use a splitter on the space character. Of your permitted characters, only `'` is going to appear in a word; anything else is going to be grammatical.

You haven't posted what version of SQL you're using, so I've going to use SQL Server 2017 syntax. If you don't have the latest version, you'll need to replace `TRANSLATE` with a nested `REPLACE` (So `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(... REPLACE(M.Detail, '¬',' '),...),'/',' '),'?',' ')`, and find a string splitter (for example, Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)).

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
CREATE TABLE [Messages] (Detail varchar(5000));

INSERT INTO [Messages]
VALUES ('Personally, I would strip out almost all the special characters, and then use a splitter on the space character. Of your permitted characters, only `''` is going to appear in a word; anything else is going to be grammatical. You haven''t posted what version of SQL you''re using, so I''ve going to use SQL Server 2017 syntax. If you don''t have the latest version, you''ll need to replace `TRANSLATE` with a nested `REPLACE` (So `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(... REPLACE(M.Detail, ''¬'','' ''),...),''/'','' ''),''?'','' '')`, and find a string splitter (for example, Jeff Moden''s [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)).'),
       ('As a note, this is going to perform **AWFULLY**. SQL Server is not designed for this type of work. I also imagine you''ll get some odd results and it''ll include numbers in there. Things like dates are going to get split out,, numbers like `9,000,000` would be treated as the words `9` and `000`, and hyperlinks will be separated.')
GO
WITH Replacements AS(
    SELECT TRANSLATE(Detail, '`¬!"£$%^&*()-_=+[{]};:@#~\|,<.>/?','                                 ') AS StrippedDetail
    FROM [Messages] M)
SELECT SS.[value], COUNT(*) AS WordCount
FROM Replacements R
     CROSS APPLY string_split(R.StrippedDetail,' ') SS
WHERE LEN(SS.[value]) > 0
GROUP BY SS.[value]
ORDER BY WordCount DESC;
GO
DROP TABLE [Messages];
```

As a note, this is going to perform **AWFULLY**. SQL Server is not designed for this type of work. I also imagine you'll get some odd results and it'll include numbers in there. Things like dates are going to get split out,, numbers like `9,000,000` would be treated as the words `9` and `000`, and hyperlinks will be separated.

Comment: That's perfectly okay. Thank you so much